# I am having an [Error] ld returned 1 exit status in C

Tags: c

I am **NEW** to the c programming language and currently writing a small code for my final project. The code below is a draft of the final product. Basically its a grading system where files will be incorporated later. But for now, I am just trying to test the program to see where I stand. I am receiving an error. 
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status. This is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main ()  
{
    int use;
    int key;
    int pass,i; 
    int a;
    do
    {
        menu (a); 
        switch(a) 
        {
            case 1:
                for(i=1;i<5;i++) 
                {
                    printf("Please enter your username and password \n");
                    scanf("%d",&use);
                    printf("");
                    scanf("%d",& pass);
                    if (use ==711 && pass ==90210) 
                    { 
                        printf("\n Student Name");
                        printf("\n student subjects/student letter grade");
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("\t\t student GPA");
                        printf("\n Please enter any key to exit");
                        scanf("%d",& key);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            case 2:
                for(i=1;i<5;i++) 
                {
                    printf("Please enter your username and password \n");
                    scanf("%d",&use);
                    printf("");
                    scanf("%d",& pass);
                    if (use ==911 && pass ==90211) 
                    {
                        printf("Would you like to update student grades?");
                    }
                    break;
                }

            case 3:
                for(i=1;i<5;i++) 
                {
                    printf("Please enter your username and password \n");
                    scanf("%d",&use);
                    printf("");
                    scanf("%d",& pass);
                    if (use ==1011 && pass ==90215) 
                    {
                        printf("\n below the amount of users that accessed the system today");
                        printf("\n **********");
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                    printf("Please try agagin");
                }
        }
    } while (a!=4);
    return 0;                     

    getch();
}


int menu(a)
{
    printf("\t Welcome to Ski Academy Portal");
    printf("\n   1. Student \t");                                                                
    printf("\n   2. Staff \t");                                                                                                                                     
    printf("\n   3. Administrative \t");                                                   
    printf("\n   4.    Exit \t");          
    printf("\n Please enter your number choice \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's compiler command you're executing and what's the complete output?

Comment: Too bad that is not the actual error message, but just the report of your build tool there was an error. Please provide the **full error message**. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears to be related to the fact that `menu` has no declaration before you attempt to use it. The warning:

```
 warning: implicit declaration of function ‘menu’
```

Is fairly self-explanatory. Depending on the compiler, that will flow through to the link stage and generate the `ld returns -1 error` because the linker cannot find the definition of a function named `menu`.

Create a declaration of `menu` at the top of your code after the includes. e.g.

```
...
#include<string.h>

int menu(a);

int main (void) {
...
```

or preferably:

```
int menu (int a);
```

Also note `'i'` and `'a'` are used uninitialized in `main()`. Make sure you provide a value for them before you attempt to use them.

Compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` (e.g. warning enabled) will tell you all of this in a concise fashion.